# Can we interconnect with other people mentally during dreaming?

Tags: sleep, dreams

In some of my dreams, I have seen people that I know, and I ask them about it the day after and they say that they saw me too. My older sister said that she had exactly the same dream as one of her male friends.

**Can we actually connect with other people mentally while sleeping?**

Comment: Are you sure the "male friend" wasn't toying with her (or vice versa)? Unless there was an objective third party to evaluate the dreams before any discussion between the participants took place, it is difficult to believe it happened that way. But rather one leading and the other agreeing to various details.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**
Telepathy is pseudoscience.

**Background**
I think you are referring to the phenomenon of **[telepathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy)**, which can be defined as

> [T]he purported transmission of information from one person to another
>   without using any of our known sensory channels or physical
>   interaction

and you ask whether telepathy is a scientifically established phenomenon.

Telepathy in general is [dismissed as being **pseudoscience**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy#cite_note-Planer1980-8) [(Jogalekar, 2013)](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/the-curious-wavefunction/belief-in-multiple-universes-requires-exceptional-vision-so-does-belief-in-telepathy/) as it has been debunked in various scientific studies (*e.g.* 
[Ayeroff & Abelson (1976)](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1976-27274-001)).

Likewise, **[dream telepathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_telepathy)** is considered [pseudoscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_telepathy). It was reportedly first documented by [Freud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmund_Freud) in the 1940s. Freud founded many other **[pseudo-scientific](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Psychoanalysis)** concepts, including [psychoanalysis](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Psychoanalysis) [(Jupp, 1977)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3749543). Ullman & Krippner from the dream laboratory in Maimonides Medical Center in New York City claimed they had proven the existence of dream telepathy in the 1960s and 70s (*e.g.* [Krippner & Ullman (1970)](http://journals.lww.com/jonmd/Abstract/1970/12000/TELEPATHY_AND_DREAMS__A_CONTROLLED_EXPERIMENT_WITH.4.aspx). However, the studies were rightfully challenged. For example, many of their studies were based on a few or even on single subjects (*e.g.* [Ullman & Krippner (1966)](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1967-03615-001) and [Krippner & Ullman (1970)](http://journals.lww.com/jonmd/Abstract/1970/12000/TELEPATHY_AND_DREAMS__A_CONTROLLED_EXPERIMENT_WITH.4.aspx)). Indeed, more recent studies have failed to replicate their findings (*e.g.*., [Belvedere & Foulkes, (1971)](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1971.33.3.783) and [Hearne (1989)](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1989-35029-001)).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Ayeroff & Abelson, *Personality and Social Psychology* (1976); **34**(2): 240-7](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1976-27274-001)

**-** [Belvedere & Foulkes, *Perceptual and Motor Skills* (1971); **33**(3)](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1971.33.3.783)

**-** [Hearne, J Soc Psychical Res (1989); **55**(814): 271-4](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1989-35029-001)

**-** [Jogalekar, *Sci Am* (August 2013)](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/the-curious-wavefunction/belief-in-multiple-universes-requires-exceptional-vision-so-does-belief-in-telepathy/)

**-** [Jupp, *Philosophy* (1977); **52**(202): 441-53](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3749543)

**-** [Krippner & Ullman J Nervous & Mental Disease (1970)](http://journals.lww.com/jonmd/Abstract/1970/12000/TELEPATHY_AND_DREAMS__A_CONTROLLED_EXPERIMENT_WITH.4.aspx)

**-** [Ullman & Krippner *Int J Neuropsych*, **2**(5): 420-37](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1967-03615-001)</sub>